# Include Require.JS with compiled bundle

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I've created a simple javascript library using requireJS. It is working fine without compiling with r.js. The structure of the project is below:

[image]

When I go to compile this code with `r.js -o build.js` it produces the following directory structure:

[image]

But I dont want to export require.js in the build. I want to include it in the same build not to let the end users to add it separately in their page.

My **build.js** file is like this:

```
({
    appDir: 'app',
    baseUrl: 'js',
    mainConfigFile: 'app/js/main.js',
    dir: 'dist',
    removeCombined: true,
    findNestedDependencies: true,
    optimize: 'uglify2',
    optimizeCSS: true,
    requireLib: 'require',
    modules: [
        {
            name: 'main'
        }
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `requireLib: 'require'` at the top level of your build configuration does nothing. The documentation [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#rename) tells you what to do. Basically, you need to define a `paths` that maps an alias for `require` to `require`, and list this alias as a dependency. With your configuration, it would be:

```
({
    appDir: 'app',
    baseUrl: 'js',
    mainConfigFile: 'app/js/main.js',
    dir: 'dist',
    removeCombined: true,
    findNestedDependencies: true,
    optimize: 'uglify2',
    optimizeCSS: true,
    // Define the mapping.
    paths: {
        requireLib: 'lib/require'
    },
    modules: [
        {
            name: 'main',
            // Use the mapping.
            include: ['requireLib']
        }
    ],
})
```

Comment: It is giving error Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/var/www/html/mkjax/dist/js/require.js' at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)

Comment: The file was removed from the built but the functionality is not working as expected. I written <script src="js/main.js"></script> in the page but it does nothing now. Can you please help me out?

Comment: It is only working by using <script src="js/lib/require.js" data-main="js/main"></script> but I want it to work as <script src="js/main.js"> and also change the name main.js to anythingelse.js